# Excel VBA: copying all rows in a range including any hidden by a filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy

I have a VBA macro that copies a table into another spreadsheet. There is a filter on this table as I often need to drill down on stuff, and often I leave rows filtered. How can I ensure my macro will copy all rows in the table and not just those selected by the filter?

At the moment I am doing this:

```
Private Sub PopulateTab(SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range)

  SourceRange.Copy

  With TargetRange
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  End With

End Sub
```

which only copies rows selected by the filter, not the whole range.

Comment: Unfilter the range, then Refilter it again

Comment: @brettdj - this is what I've done, see my own answer below

Comment: This cant be the only answer? I have 25 filters...

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I unfilter the range first:

```
Sub Unfilter(Sheet As Worksheet)

  Dim Fltr As Filter
  Dim iFiltr As Long

  With Sheet.AutoFilter
    For iFiltr = 1 To .Filters.Count
        If .Filters(iFiltr).On Then
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=iFiltr
        End If
    Next iFiltr
  End With

End Sub
```

I don't store the filter selection as don't care about leaving everything unfiltered.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to remember the filters, you only need a single line of code:

```
Sub UnfilterMe(Sheet As Worksheet)
    Sheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```